# Creating a table that multiplies height by weight

Tags: php

How would I create a table that multiples height by weight?

I have no idea how to figure it out!

I am trying to create a BMI calculator.

```
// collect values from a form sent with method=get

$min_weight = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["min_weight"]);
$max_weight = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["max_weight"]);
$min_height = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["min_height"]);
$max_height = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["max_height"]);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Key:</td>
      <td class="good show">Healthy (20-25)</td>
      <td cla ss="warning show">Overweight (25-30)</td>
      <td class="bad show">Unhealthy ( -20 or 30+)</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<table border="1">
<?php 
echo "<tr><td>Height &rarr;<br>Weight &darr;</td>";
for ( $i = $min_height; $i <= $max_height; $i+=5 ) 
{
    echo "<td>{$i}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
for ( $j = $min_weight; $j <= $max_weight; $j+=5 ) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$j}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: `$mul = $height * $weight;` ??? The problem is't clear for me.

Comment: I can't understand what you want to do either, please elaborate. By the way, avoid mysql, it is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Try mysqli or PDO instead. And I'd use `method="post"` when it comes to form submitting.

Comment: @alex if the page/form is only used to **show** information, not **modify/update** information in the database, then `get` is the proper method for the form. People will also be able to bookmark the page if desired

Comment: You are correct, I didn't realize he was only displaying the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job, i've also put some isset()'s:

```
<?php

// collect values from a form sent with method=get

$min_weight = isset($_GET["min_weight"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["min_weight"]):0;
$max_weight = isset($_GET["max_weight"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["max_weight"]):0;
$min_height = isset($_GET["min_height"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["min_height"]):0;
$max_height = isset($_GET["max_height"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["max_height"]):0;

?>

<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Key:</td>
      <td class="good show">Healthy (20-25)</td>
      <td class="warning show">Overweight (25-30)</td>
      <td class="bad show">Unhealthy ( -20 or 30+)</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<?php
$table = '<table border="1">';
$table .= '<tr><td>Height &rarr;<br>Weight &darr;</td>';
for ($i = $min_height;$i <= $max_height;$i += 5){
    $table .= "<td>$i</td>";
}
$table .= "</tr>";
for($j = $min_weight; $j <= $max_weight;$j += 5){
    $table .= "<tr><td>$j</td>";
    for ($i = $min_height;$i <= $max_height;$i += 5){
        $table .= '<td>'. $i * $j .'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this works is it wrong to have the table border outside of the php tags?

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Key:</td>
      <td class="good show">Healthy (20-25)</td>
      <td class="warning show">Overweight (25-30)</td>
      <td class="bad show">Unhealthy ( -20 or 30+)</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<table border="1">
<?php 
echo "<tr><td>Height &rarr;<br>Weight &darr;</td>";

for ( $j = $min_height; $j <= $max_height; $j+=5 ) 
{
echo "<td>{$j}</td>";
}

for ( $i = $min_weight; $i <= $max_weight; $i+=5 ) 
{
echo "<tr><td>{$i}</td>";
for ( $j = $min_height; $j <= $max_height; $j+=5 ) 
{
$var = number_format(($i)/(($j/100)*($j/100)),'2','.','');
{
echo "<td class='warning'>";

}

echo $var;
echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not wrong, you may also use `echo '<table border="1">';` in your php code.